# iOS Tabs speaking to each other

Tags: ios, tabs

I have an app where there are two basic functions, delineated by being on separate tabs on a UITabBarController. Each tab has a particular button that when pressed should, as a separate function to its normal activity, also asynchronously tell the other tab to nil its data. How can I access one tab from the other?

Comment: maybe the UITabBarController should tell every non-selected view controller to nil its data

Comment: Sounds like a very rigid design to me... have you considered using a mediator design pattern instead? (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html or http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/objective-c/9781430233305/chapter-11-mediator/what_is_the_mediator_pattern_question) Or perhaps even sending `NSNotification`s in lieu of having all your controllers know about each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good use for notifications (as in `NSNotification`, not local or push notifications).

You should have some sort of model for each view controller in each tab. Each model can publish its notification while registering for the other. This way, neither view controller or model needs to actually know about the other directly.

When the user taps a button, the view controller tells its model to publish its notification. The other one will get the notification and act accordingly.

See the docs for `NSNotificationCenter` and `NSNotification` for details.

Comment: +1: I agree, it's best to reduce the knowledge each controller has about the others -- "loose coupling" if you will.

Comment: Plus this approach scales a lot better as more tabs are added.

Answer (score 1):

## Definition of "tabs" for UITabBarController

```
// define controllers for each tab
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// define tab bar controller, "self" is a UITabBarController
self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController1, viewController2, nil];
```

From this point, if you need to access a particular tab, you want to do so via the "viewController1" or "viewController2" objects.  Each of these UIViewController objects would presumably have access to certain data in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can access each of your viewControllers from TabBarController's `viewControllers` property, and iterate through them. Zero all but the live one (self).

Put it into a GCD dispatch queue for asynchronicity.

```
    - (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender {
        NSLog (@"%@ %@",self,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

            //do normal stuff here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            for (id viewController in  [[self tabBarController] viewControllers]) {
                if ((viewController != self)
                && ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(zeroData)])) {
                    [viewController performSelector:@selector(zeroData)];
                }
            }
        });
    }



    - (void) zeroData
    {
        NSLog (@"%@ %@",self,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
                //each view controller should zero out it's own data
                //in a method called "zeroData"
    }
```

If you try this and look at the logs, you will see that it leaves the current vc alone but sends `zeroData` to the others...

Answer (score 0):

Are your tabs core-data driven? If you use a NSFetchedResultsController then you get notifications for free through the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol. Otherwise, NSNotification like rmaddy suggests.